# Ошибка при парсинге значения «direction». Потерянное объявление

Tags: javascript

Если напишу так то то блок улетит влево:

```
$(".templateWindow").animate({"left" : "-150%"}, 300 , funcCallBack);
```

А если так то будет ошибка:

```
var direction = "left";
$(".templateWindow").animate({direction : "-150%"}, 300 , funcCallBack);
```

Ошибка при парсинге значения «direction».  Потерянное объявление.
Из-за чего это происходит(typeof возвращает string для обоих)?

Comment: Может  `-150` следует вынести из кавычек, чтобы значение не воспринимало как строку?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не, обратите внимание, что там `%`

Comment: @Grundy конкатенация не прокатит?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не совсем понял куда вы ее хотите впихнуть, и чем она будет отличаться от того что есть сейчас?

Comment: @Grundy `-150 + "%"` чтоб число воспринимало как число а не строку, а процент уже бонус)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но это же вернет как раз _"-150%"_ :-) я честно говоря не вижу разницы :)

Comment: Кстати я не понял что значит улетит влево? может время исполнения анимации маленькое? вот увеличил я  и работает медленно без улёта: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljxdu6eq/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34304/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы пишете `{direction: ..}` , вы задаете свойство direction объекту. Разницы между `{direction: .. }` и `{"direction": ..}` нет. Чтобы взять из переменной название свойства, которое вы хотите задать, Вам нужно сделать так:

```
var direction = "left";
var opts={}
opts[direction]="-150%";
$(".templateWindow").animate(opts, 300 , funcCallBack);
```

Comment: А чем это отличается от `$(".templateWindow").animate({"left" : "-150%"}, 300 , funcCallBack);` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, тем что `{direction: ..}` тоже самое что и `{"direction": ..}`, а как вы видите - "direction" - не равно "left"

Comment: Тем что мы можем в зависимости от какого-то условия задать direction = "right"

Comment: @Grundy так я и не про дирекшн. я про лефт)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ага, значит я не так понял :-) но Darth уже привел пример :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать [вычислимые имена свойств из ECMA 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

```
// Computed property names (ES6)
var prop = "foo";
var o = {
  [prop]: "hey",
  ["b" + "ar"]: "there",
};
```

В вашем случае это будет

```
$(".templateWindow").animate({[direction] : "-150%"}, 300 , funcCallBack);
```

Comment: А как проверить что  вычислимые имена свойств доступны в конкретном браузере?

Comment: @manking, если не доступны - получите ошибку :-)

Comment: @manking, узнать какие браузеры поддерживают, [можно например тут](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_computed_properties)

Comment: Я имею ввиду автоматически проверить доступность этого свойства у браузера. Чтобы если оно не поддерживается то было выбрано другое решение.

Comment: @manking, проверить можно, например попробовать выполнить `eval("var x = 'y';({ [x]: 1 }).y === 1;")` если поддерживается вернет true, если нет - кинет ошибку.

Comment: или так: `new Function("var x='y'; return ({ [x] : 1}).y === 1")` если не поддерживается будет ошибка